# PCI compliant voice API services (like Twilio)

Tags: twilio, credit-card, pci-compliance

I have a client who would like to accept credit card payments over the phone automatically.  While normally I'd use something like Stripe for the credit card processing, I recognize that ultimately I'd have to temporarily store the credit card information on my server to pass it on to my processor, and even more importantly, whatever voice service I'm using (like Twilio) would also see that information and have to be PCI compliant.

Question:

**Are there any PCI-compliant voice API providers (like Twilio)?
If not, how might it be possible to create such a set up where I could automatically accept credit cards over the phone?**

Answer (score 0):

The search term you are looking for is "IVR Payment System" - there are a bunch of companies out there offering this including several with PCI-DSS Level 1 certification. Basically this approach involves you transferring the call to the payment IVR, and then it will transfer the call back after collecting the credit card information.